# Dropdown menu not appearing on mouse click

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Attempting to implement a simple CSS drop down menu.

I am unable to find the issue in the following HTML/CSS code as to why this implementation does not work.

As you can see clicking on the header buttons simply do not elicit any response.

If any poster versed in CSS could inform me of what the issue could be.

```
/* Gnav-menu-label:after CSS ---------------------*/
```

Is where the issues lies I believe.

```css
/* START header CSS */
/* Gnav-active CSS ---------------------*/

.Gnav-active {
    position: relative;
}

/* Gnav-wrapper CSS ---------------------*/

#WebsitePrimaryNav.Gnav-wrapper,#WebsitePrimaryNav.Subnav-wrapper {
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
}

#WebsiteFooterNav.Footernav-wrapper *,#WebsiteFooterNav.Footernav-wrapper :after,#WebsiteFooterNav.Footernav-wrapper :before,#WebsitePrimaryNav.Gnav-wrapper,#WebsitePrimaryNav.Gnav-wrapper *,#WebsitePrimaryNav.Gnav-wrapper :after,#WebsitePrimaryNav.Gnav-wrapper :before,#WebsiteSecondaryNav.Subnav-wrapper *,#WebsiteSecondaryNav.Subnav-wrapper :after,#WebsiteSecondaryNav.Subnav-wrapper :before {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav.Gnav-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom-color: #cad9e3;
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    height: 80px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    fill: #2d2d2d;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;

}

.Gnav-active #WebsitePrimaryNav.Gnav-wrapper {
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: visible;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav.Gnav-wrapper, #WebsiteSecondaryNav.Subnav-wrapper {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/* Gnav CSS ---------------------*/

body #WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav{
    font-family: inherit;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

/* Gnav-menu-wrapper CSS ---------------------*/

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-wrapper {
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    order: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

/* Gnav-menu-content CSS ---------------------*/

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-content {
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
    border-top: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    box-shadow: none;
}

/* Gnav-menu CSS ---------------------*/

#WebsitePrimaryNav.Gnav-wrapper ul{
    list-style: none;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    max-height: none;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

/* Gnav-menu-item has-submenu CSS ---------------------*/

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-item {
    padding-top: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}


#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-item.has-submenu .Gnav-menu-label {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#WebsitePrimaryNav.Gnav-wrapper a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-label:focus, #WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-label:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-item.has-submenu .Gnav-menu-label:after {
    display: block;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-item.is-open>.Gnav-menu-label {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #2d2d2d;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-label:focus{
    outline-offset: -3px;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-label {
    height: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: inherit;
    transition: color .1s ease,background-color .1s ease;
}

/* Gnav-menu-label:after CSS ---------------------*/

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-item.is-open>.Gnav-menu-label:after {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-item.is-open>.Gnav-submenus {
    max-height:none;
    visibility:visible
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-item.has-submenu .Gnav-menu-label:after, #WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-item:before {
    display: none;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-item.has-submenu .Gnav-menu-label:focus:after, #WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-item.has-submenu .Gnav-menu-label:hover:after {
    display: block;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-item.is-open>.Gnav-menu-label:after {
    transform: none;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-label:after {
 position:absolute;
 right:20px;
 top:50%;
 margin-top:-1.33px;
 border-width:4px 4px 0;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:#b2b2b2 transparent transparent;
 display:none;
 transition:-webkit-transform .1s ease;
 transition:transform .1s ease;
 transition:transform .1s ease,-webkit-transform .1s ease;
 -webkit-transform-origin:50% 33%;
 transform-origin:50% 33%;
 content:""
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-submenus {
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-label:focus,#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-label:hover {
background-color:#f4f4f4
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-label:after {
 bottom:9px;
 left:50%;
 right:auto;
 top:auto;
 margin-left:-3px;
 margin-top:auto;
 border-width:3px 3px 0;
 display:none
}

/* Gnav-submenus CSS ---------------------*/

#WebsitePrimaryNav.Gnav-wrapper ul{
    list-style: none;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-submenus {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    display: none;
    transition: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-menu-item.is-open>.Gnav-submenus {
    max-height: 75vh;
    display: flex;
}

/* Gnav-submenu-wrapper CSS ---------------------*/

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-submenu-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-submenu-wrapper+.Gnav-submenu-wrapper:before {
position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0 5px;
    border-top:1px solid #f3f3f3;
    content:""
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-submenu-wrapper {
    min-width:240px;
    padding:25px 0;
    flex-shrink:0;
    white-space:nowrap;

}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-submenu-wrapper+.Gnav-submenu-wrapper {
    border-left:1px solid #f3f3f3;

}

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-submenu-wrapper+.Gnav-submenu-wrapper:before {
    display:none
}

/* Gnav-submenu-headline CSS ---------------------*/

#WebsitePrimaryNav .Gnav-submenu-headline {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 10px 35px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #767676;
}
```

```html
<!-- START header HTML -->
<div class="Gnav-active" style="">
  <header id="WebsitePrimaryNav" class="Gnav-wrapper" role="banner">
    <nav class="Gnav" role="navigation">
      <div class="Gnav-menu-wrapper">
        <div class="Gnav-menu-content">
          <ul class="Gnav-menu" data-gnav-scrollable="mobile">

            <li class="Gnav-menu-item has-submenu " id="xxxxxxxx">
              <a href="#" class="Gnav-menu-label" data-type="item" role="button">
                                Articles
                            </a>
              <ul class="Gnav-submenus" data-type="popup" role="group">
                <li class="Gnav-submenu-wrapper">
                  <h5 class="Gnav-submenu-headline">Articles</h5>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="Gnav-menu-item has-submenu " id="xxxxxxxx">
              <a href="#" class="Gnav-menu-label" data-type="item" role="button">
                                Guides
                            </a>
              <ul class="Gnav-submenus" data-type="popup" role="group">

                <li class="Gnav-submenu-wrapper">
                  <h5 class="Gnav-submenu-headline">Guides</h5>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you don't have a click-event in CSS. You have to use `:hover` or`:active` pseudo-classes.

if you want to display your Subnav with pure CSS u should use `:hover`. It's important that the hidden Subnav is a Child of the hovered Element. Then u can solve it like that:

```
#nav ul .mainNav .subnav {
    display: none; /* Subnav initially hidden */
}
#nav ul .mainNav:hover .subnav {
    display: block; /* Subnav shown while hovering mainNav */
}
```

Comment: There is a click event present in the CSS.